# Get object where the value of key is equal to array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the corresponding object from data where the value (for example `888`) of a key (for example `id`) is equal to the value of a looping variable (i.e. `id[i] == 888`)?

My data looks like:

```
{
    "players": {
        "player6": {
            "id": "777",
            "name": "Barak Obama",
            "trck": "obama",
            "img": "dev/obama.jpg",
            "img2x": "dev/obama_2x.jpg"
        },
        "player23": {
            "id": "888",
            "name": "George Bush",
            "trck": "bush",
            "img": "dev/bush.jpg",
            "img2x": "dev/bush_2x.jpg"
        },
        "player87": {
            "id": "999",
            "name": "Bill Clinton",
            "trck": "clinton",
            "img": "dev/clinton.jpg",
            "img2x": "dev/clinton_2x.jpg"
        }
  },
  "coaches": {…},
  "manager": {…},
  "staff": {…}
}
```

To start with, I have an array wich consists of one or multiple numbers (for example `[888,999]`). They do represent the IDs of selected players (not necessarily all of them, just one or multiple ones).

Now, how can I get all the corresponding data of the associated player (like name, trck, img, etc.) where the key `id` equals the number from an array (looping) in the value?

- loop through my array `[888,999]`
- get the data from all players where `id == 888` first, and then `999`
- use this data (name, id, trck, img, etc.) to add some HTML markup with those values to the page

**Update:** I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough (and exactly following your description):

```
var ids = [888,999];

$.each(ids, function (i, id) {
    $.each(data.players, function (key, player) {
        if (player.id == id) {
            // add player.name, .id, .trck, .img, etc to page

            return false; // break the execution of $.each();
        }
    });
});
```

Note that `player.id == id` makes use of the automatic type conversion in JS, so it's very much intentional that it is not a strict comparison (`===`).

Comment: WOW. This seams to work! I'll have to try this out more, but I'm confident this might work :-)

Comment: If your `data.players` is too big, you can consider break the second `each` loop to improve performances.

Comment: @PatrickFerreira You are right, the inner loop should break in any case. I've added that. (If `players` gets *really* big I'd consider creating a `playersById` index and cut out the inner loop, but really... if it's gets big enough so that the above nested loop causes performance difficulties, then I'd say that there's something fundamentally wrong with the page's design.)

Comment: cool thank you very much @Tomalak ! learned a lot with this lil snipped! :-) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Where `data` is your object.

Return a "filtered" players object.

```
var filterPlayers = function(ids){
  var obj = {};
  for(var player in data.players){
    if(ids.indexOf(data.players[player].id) >= 0){
        obj[player] = data.players[player];
    }
  }

  return obj;
};
```

Or, invoke a callback for each match.

```
var filterPlayers = function(ids, callback){
  for(var player in data.players){
    if(ids.indexOf(data.players[player].id) >= 0){
        callback(data.players[player]);
    }
  }
};

filterPlayers([888, 999], function(player){
    document.write("<span>" + player.name + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the keys and build a new object with the found items.

```js
var object1 = { "players": { "player6": { "id": "777", "name": "Barak Obama", "trck": "obama", "img": "dev/obama.jpg", "img2x": "dev/obama_2x.jpg" }, "player23": { "id": "888", "name": "George Bush", "trck": "bush", "img": "dev/bush.jpg", "img2x": "dev/bush_2x.jpg" }, "player87": { "id": "999", "name": "Bill Clinton", "trck": "clinton", "img": "dev/clinton.jpg", "img2x": "dev/clinton_2x.jpg" } }, "coaches": {}, "manager": {}, "staff": {} },
    object2 = {},
    search = [777, 888];

Object.keys(object1.players).forEach(function (k) {
    if (search.indexOf(+object1.players[k].id) > -1) {
        object2[k] = object1.players[k];
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

If you like to get an array, then you could use this

```js
var object1 = { "players": { "player6": { "id": "777", "name": "Barak Obama", "trck": "obama", "img": "dev/obama.jpg", "img2x": "dev/obama_2x.jpg" }, "player23": { "id": "888", "name": "George Bush", "trck": "bush", "img": "dev/bush.jpg", "img2x": "dev/bush_2x.jpg" }, "player87": { "id": "999", "name": "Bill Clinton", "trck": "clinton", "img": "dev/clinton.jpg", "img2x": "dev/clinton_2x.jpg" } }, "coaches": {}, "manager": {}, "staff": {} },
    result= [],
    search = [777, 888];

Object.keys(object1.players).forEach(function (k) {
    if (search.indexOf(+object1.players[k].id) > -1) {
        result.push(object1.players[k]);
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I'd consider `if (~array.indexOf(x))` the sort of clever where I'm not sure if it's a good idea to have it in my code - why not the dead-obvious `if (array.indexOf(x) > -1)`?

Comment: @Tomalak, better that way?

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
var players = {
    "players": {
        "player6": {
            "id": "777",
            "name": "Barak Obama",
            "trck": "obama",
            "img": "dev/obama.jpg",
            "img2x": "dev/obama_2x.jpg"
        },
        "player23": {
            "id": "888",
            "name": "George Bush",
            "trck": "bush",
            "img": "dev/bush.jpg",
            "img2x": "dev/bush_2x.jpg"
        },
        "player87": {
            "id": "999",
            "name": "Bill Clinton",
            "trck": "clinton",
            "img": "dev/clinton.jpg",
            "img2x": "dev/clinton_2x.jpg"
        }
  },
  "coaches": {},
  "manager": {},
  "staff": {}
}

function get_player_by_property(players, property, value){
    for (var player_key in players) {
       if (players.hasOwnProperty(player_key)) {
           if (players[player_key][property] == value)
               return players[player_key];
       }
    }
}

console.log( get_player_by_property(players.players, 'id', '777') );
```